# How to add Download link to File field

Tags: views, 8, files

I would like to know how I can make File field type display the upload as a download link, instead of having a link. So that user can just click and it will download).

The file field type, I added to a custom Content Type, which I created programmatically through a module.

Currently it looks like below, when I click the link, it takes to the uploaded file page. I would like to have it download instead.

Or maybe is there a way to change the view or add additional view to File types for download? or maybe change view for Content Type where it displays the Download link for the file?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to update the link tag, then just use the `download` attribute, it should do the trick.

I've wrote a tiny [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/45ug9p7t/1/) for you https://jsfiddle.net/45ug9p7t/1/

Keep in mind that not every browser has implemented this, [check it out](https://caniuse.com/#feat=download)

Comment: The link will change actually, I have found File Download Link module which allwos this